# Construct a circuit of given equivalent resistance using a set of given resistors?

Tags: number-theory

Here is a fun little problem I thought of. It involves electronic circuits, but it's really a number theory problem.

We have a box containing an infinite number of resistors with resistance $R$. We wish to construct a circuit consisting only of resistors from the box and wires such that the equivalent resistance is $R'$. Furthermore, $R$ and $R'$ are positive rational numbers. Is this task always possible?

Note: the circuit must use FINITELY many resistors. This assumption may or may not be relevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is always possible.  Let $R=\frac{p}{q}$ and $R'=\frac{p'}{q'}$ be in ohms.

Put $pq'$ resistors in parallel, the equivalent resistance would be $\frac{R}{pq'}=\frac{1}{qq'}$ ohms.  Put $p'q$ of these in series.

Comment: Yes it's really quite an easy problem. I just thought it was cute.

Comment: A better problem would be to have a given set of rational resistances ${R_1,R_2,\ldots,R_n}$, then to try to find the minimum number of resistors to get a given rational resistance.

Comment: Yes but that's too general no? How would you formulate the problem so as to admit an answer? Do you mean design an algorithm that gives the minimum number of resistors and constructs the circuit, given an input set $R_1,..,R_n$?

Comment: Yes, it is very general.  The answer would probably not be an expression but would be in the form of an algorithm.

Answer (score 2):

Sure it's possible.

Let the ratio between $R'$ and $R$ be $r$, a rational number. (As $R$ and $R'$ are both rational, so is their ratio).

Express $r=p/q$.

You can make a resistance of $R/q$ by wiring up $q$ resistors in parallel. You can then make a resistance of $Rp/q$ by wiring up $p$ lots of $q$ resistors in series. This is $Rp/q=R'$, as requested.

Comment: If you mean $\frac{R'}{R}=\frac{p}{q}$, then you should perhaps say "the ratio between $R'$ and $R$."